# How to clear output content in the web using Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am debugging a JavaScript program with Firebug. It is simple to clear JavaScript code in its Command Editor just by clicking *Clear*.

Now, how to clear output content in the website using Firebug?

[image: Website output and Command Line code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from refreshing the browser each time you could run this in your console.

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

Or while you are experimenting you could extend the document object for convenience...

```
document.clear = function () { document.body.innerHTML = ''; }
// usage
document.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can run this in the [Command Line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line)/[Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor) to clear the website:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

Or you can delete the output element from within the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel):

1. Right-click the output on the page and choose *Inspect Element with Firebug* or switch to the *HTML* panel and select it there.
2. Hit <kbd>Del</kbd> on the keyboard or right-click the element and choose *Delete Element* from the context menu.